# Conversion failed converting date in order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
SELECT app.[Pap_id]
    ,reg.[p_id]
    ,[p_name]
    ,[p_age]
    ,[p_gender]
    ,[p_mob]
    ,[p_specificId]
    ,app.[ap_date]
    ,app.[reqst_txt]
FROM [dbo].[tblpatientReg] reg
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblAppoinment] app ON app.[P_id] = reg.[p_id]
WHERE app.[p_status] = 1
ORDER BY convert(DATE, app.[ap_date], 105) ASC
```

Comment: What's confusing about the error?  Have a look at your data.  You have some `app.[ap_date]` field(s) that aren't properly formatted to be dates.  (This is why you should *never* store dates as `varchar`)

Comment: Please, show a sample of `app.[ap_date]` column data.

Comment: app.[ap_date] column data 17/07/2016

Comment: Check your value in the column [ap_date] there may any incompetible format.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
ORDER BY CASE isDate(app.[ap_date]) WHEN 1 THEN
    convert(DATE, app.[ap_date], 105) 
ELSE NULL END ASC
```

If you have bad data types they all will be grouped.